# SQL: Can't get unique names/users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which works perfectly:

```
SELECT
     u.id
   , u.mobile
   , u.name
   , (NOW() - u.authenticationTime) AS authenticateTimeDifference
   , u.IP
   , c.providerid
   , c.requestid
   , c.status
   , u.port
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id =
IF (
        c.providerid = 2
      , c.requestid
      , c.providerid
      ) WHERE (
      c.providerid = 2
      AND c.status = 1
      )
   OR c.requestid = 2

ORDER BY authenticateTimeDifference
```

Now I wanted to only select DISTINCT `u.name` fields (or unique users) so I changed `u.name` to `DISTINCT(u.name)` but I am getting error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(u.name) , 
(NOW() - u.authenticationTime) AS au' at line 4
```

I also tried adding `GROUP BY u.name` but still no luck.

Can anybody tell how do I select unique names/users through above query ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: For each grouped `name` value, which values do you want to select for the other columns `id`, `mobile`, etc...?? please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Also, where did you find `unique` being defined in the documentation?

Comment: What is that `UNIQUE()` ? The job of `group by` will return all unique names.

Comment: sorry i changed to `UNIQUE` to `DISTINCT` but still getting the same error

Comment: I just want to get distinct names

Comment: you do not need distinct the group by does it for you, and its not `DISTINCT(u.name)` its `DISTINCT u.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `group by`:

```
SELECT
     u.id
   , u.mobile
   , u.name
   , (NOW() - u.authenticationTime) AS authenticateTimeDifference
   , u.IP
   , c.providerid
   , c.requestid
   , c.status
   , u.port
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id =
IF (
        c.providerid = 2
      , c.requestid
      , c.providerid
      ) WHERE (
      c.providerid = 2
      AND c.status = 1
      )
   OR c.requestid = 2
GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY authenticateTimeDifference
```

Then you have to decide what to do with the other values. Should they show the lowest value, highest value, average, etc.? Since you want to group on the name only, you have to pick one for the fields not in the `group by`.

Comment: oh means i was putting group by at wrong place. Thanks I will mark this as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

According to me `Distinct` must occur just after select. SO your query should be like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.mobile, u.name, (NOW() - u.authenticationTime) AS authenticateTimeDifference
, u.IP, c.providerid, c.requestid, c.status, u.port
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id =
IF (c.providerid = 2, c.requestid, c.providerid) 
WHERE (
  c.providerid = 2
  AND c.status = 1
  )
OR c.requestid = 2

ORDER BY authenticateTimeDifference
```